# slideToggle doesn't work jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, slide

I've recently been trying jQuery and I have tried to create a spring like object, but there seems to be some problem with `slideToggle()`. Any help?

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <td>
        <div class="header">Spring!</div>
        <div class="footer">Spring!</div>
        <div class="header">Spring!</div>
        <div class="footer">Spring!</div>
        <div class="header">Spring!</div>
        <div class="footer">Spring!</div>
        <div class="header">Spring!</div>
        <div class="footer">Spring!</div>
        <div class="header">Spring!</div>
        <div class="footer">Spring!</div>
        <div class="header">Spring!</div>
        <div class="footer">Spring!</div>
    </td>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
  .header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header").hover(function () {
        $(".footer").slideToggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot some `)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header").hover(function () {
        $(".footer").slideToggle();
    }) //forgot a ")" here
})  //forgot a ")" here
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qLZY/)

Answer (score 0):

Your missing brackets and semi-colons.Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header").hover(function(){
        $(".footer").slideToggle();
    }); //here you were missing ")" and ";"
}); //here you were missing ")" and ";"
```

**Updated answer:**

I suggested you to use `.on()` method instead of shorthand operator. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. You can also do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseenter','.header',function(){
        $(".footer").slideToggle();
    }).on('mouseleave','.header',  function(){
       $(".footer").slideToggle();
   });
});
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/MsC9k/1/

Answer (score 0):

Only your script needs to be corrected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header").hover(function(){
        $(".footer").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Also its nothing to do with JS but a "tr" has also been missed. :)